# Why does a self-importing module execute once in some cases and twice in others?

Tags: python, python-import

Consider for example the following, with CPython 3.10.6:

```
$ echo 'import x; import x; print("Executing"); import x; import x' >x.py
$ python3 -c 'import x'
Executing
$ python3 x.py
Executing
Executing
$ python3 -m x
Executing
Executing
```

It makes sense to me that despite four `import`s, the file doesn't actually execute four or five times, because Python doesn't reexecute a module on every import. Otherwise self-import wouldn't work in the first place, because it would recurse infinitely. What surprises me is that while `import x` executes the file only once, as one might expect, other ways of running the file will execute it twice. Why does the extra execution occur? Is this behavior ever useful?

Comment: My guess - when a file is ***first*** imported, a module object is created and subsequent imports are basically "ignored" (because the object for that module already exists). When you run `import x` directly, a module object is created and the imports inside the file are ignored (so print once). When you execute the file, a module object is only created after the first import and subsequent imports are ignored (two prints - original file and first import). (this is a comment and not an answer because it's my guess and not backed-up by official docs)

Comment: If you execute the file as a *script*, it first creates a module named `__main__`. Then the first `import x` actually creates a module named `x`. The two modules are otherwise identical, but they are still distinct modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can more easily see what's going on when you change the code slightly from

```py
import x
import x
print("Executing...")
import x
import x
```

to include the executing module's name

```py
import x
import x
print(f"Executing {__name__}...")
import x
import x
```

The output of the second script is shown below

```
Executing x...
Executing __main__...
```

The module that's executing isn't `x`, it's `__main__` ([more details on `__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#name-main)). Because two separate modules (even though code from the same file is running), the import causes it to execute a second time.

The duplicate import isn't very useful, however it is common to see some Python packages which have a CLI while will use a block to run the module as a CLI application like so

```py
# do stuff that's needed everywhere

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print("cool stuff only when executed as a top-level module")
```

Comment: It sounds like the whole file is executed twice, and a redundant module object is created, merely so one copy can have a `__name__` of `"__main__"` and the other copy can have a `__name__` more like its file name. That's kinda nuts. You'd think module objects would just have a flag indicating whether they're the main module, instead.